# Why is my default attribute accessor not being overwritten?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, getter, overwrite, accessor

I have an Article model. The database schema has several columns including 'title'. I am trying to provide my own getter in place of the method_missing-provided getter. At present I am trying simply:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def title
    "blah"
  end
end
```

but when I reload the view the title field continues to be sourced from the database. (My server environment is development and I'm riding Rails 3.1.0.) Any ideas?

Comment: Can you include the line of the view where you're using the attribute? That looks like it should work.

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but have you stopped and restarted the local development server?

Comment: @Emily, I agree it looks like it should work!  =-)  The view looks like:
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :title, :rows => 2 %>
  </div>

Comment: @jerhinesmith, I just now stopped and restarted the server -- same behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input helpers don't use the normal accessor if there is a 'before_type_cast' variant, so in your case, it is accessing `title_before_type_cast`.

Either also define that, or choose another method name altogether. I would advise the latter, because overriding accessors is confusing, even without this complication. Don't fight ActiveRecord, you won't win.

Comment: I'm about to just go the novel method name route (I appreciate the fight advice), but I'm still curious about this problem. I tried defining `title_before_type_cast` both instead and then as well as `title`, but in neither case was "blah" provided to the helper. Why do you suppose that didn't work? Thanks.

Comment: That also confuses me. It should work, if I'm interpreting the source correctly: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/75366cb82dc6fa4b3dada2a450dda18496f3eddd/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1122